# How do I clean up a mesh the right way so the bevel tool doesn't deform my selected mesh?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bevel

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Hello, so I want to use the Bevel tool like in my first picture to bevel the edges of my mesh but once I use it it turns out completely deformed like in my second picture. What is the cause of this and what what do I need to look out for or do to change that?

I think the cause is double edges with the info of some other posts I read but there is no specific description on how double edges are even spotted. Is there a tool that does the highlighting? What would be the best way to go about this?

Best

[image]

Comment: maybe you have flipped faces? or inner faces? if it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I tried many tutorials on flipped faces and searched for inner faces  but still didn't work, so added the file above

Answer (score 2):

You're bevelling the edges of the face and increasing the bevel so much that it's overlapping. The actual geometry of your object is fine. Looking at your first image, it looks as if you just want to bevel the corners on the ends in which case you should go into edge select mode (2 on the keyboard - 1 in the image below) and select the two end edges of your object (2 below) before you bevel.
[image]
This will give you the result below which I assume is what you're trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Remove Doubles command was replaced with Merge by Distance, but it's still in the same location. In Edit mode, go up to the Mesh menu, then Cleanup, and finally Merge By Distance. You will get the contextual popup down in the left corner where you can adjust how close the vertices should be before they are merged.

If that's what you are asking, that is.